# How can I push value to url in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to push some text to url route in onChange method of an input like this :

```
function Header(props) {
 return (
  <div>
     <input type="radio" onChange={ (e)=> props.history.push(`/${e.target.value}`) } >
  </div>
)
```

But it throws multiple errors and crashes :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

How can use history.push properly or how can I push some text to route url manually from anywhere in react ?

Comment: Are you trying to change the route when radio input is changed?

Comment: @Yousaf yes sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message suggests that `history` prop is `undefined`, meaning its not passed to your component as a prop which can happen depending on the hierarchy of the components in your app.

Use one of the following options to get access to `history`:

- Use `useHistory` hook

  ```
  import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

  function Header(props) {
     const routerHistory = useHistory();

     return (
      <div>
         <input type="radio" onChange={(e)=> routerHistory.push(`/${e.target.value}`)}>
      </div>
    )
  }
  ```
- Use `withRouter` higher order component

  ```
  import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

  function Header(props) {
     return (
      <div>
         <input type="radio" onChange={(e)=> props.history.push(`/${e.target.value}`)}>
      </div>
    )
  }

  export default withRouter(Header);
  ```

For details on `withRouter` and `useHistory`, see:

- [React Router - useHistory Hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)
- [React Router - withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)